# Unique Identifier for iCloud / CloudKit User

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, icloud, cloudkit

Is there a better solution (then the possible workaround below) to get an UUID for a iCloud / CloudKit User? 
 So it's possible to detect if the user already did something (on a different device) with same iCloud account.

Possible workaround:

- Create UUID and store it in the private database

  - Disadvantage: uses extra database requests

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a possible solution:

**Swift 2**

```
CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID(completionHandler: { (recordID: CKRecordID?, error: NSError?) in
    print(recordID?.recordName) // UUID String for iCloud user
})
```

**Swift 3**

```
CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID(completionHandler: { (recordID: CKRecordID?, error: Error?) in
    print(recordID?.recordName) // UUID String for iCloud user
})
```

This id is the same across all devices using the same iCloud Account.

Comment: For more recent versions of swift change 'NSError' to 'Error'